# Why isn't my CodeIgniter app sending emails on smtp?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to send mail using CodeIgniter. I don't get any errors; in fact I get the success message designed in the system, but the email won't go through. The form details, however, get recorded in my database. Can you help me fix this please? Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to send the mail using a GoDaddy shared hosting by the way.

Here's my email.php configuration:

```
<?php

        $config = array(

          'protocol' => 'smtp',
          'smtp_host' => 'server',
          'smtp_port' => 80,
          'smtp_timeout' => 7,
          'smtp_user' => 'blabla', 
          'smtp_pass' => 'blabla', 
          'mailtype' => 'html',
          'charset' => 'utf-8',
          'newline' => "\r\n",
          'wordwrap' => TRUE

        );?>
```

Comment: You don't have 'mailpath' set, what email program are you using? sendmail? [http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html?highlight=email#setting-email-preferences]

Answer (score 2):

SMTP ports are usually 25, 2525, or 587. Changing your SMTP port number should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy has a tendency to lock down alot on their shared hosting. There is a similar Stack Overflow answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219209/codeigniter-email-class-with-godaddy-email-hosting-issues

Another option is using a third party SMTP service. I have GoDaddy hosting myself and I use SMTP2Go.

I had to use port80.smtpcorp.com as my host and port 443.

Hope that information helps!

Comment: I'll try that. What if I want to use SENDMAIL? how's the config for that?